# Apache passenger overriding all domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, laravel, passenger

I recently installed passenger apache module on my apache2 server so as to be able to serve my ruby on rails app.

I have installed - apache2 server, rvm, gem rails, gem passenger, passenger-install-apache2-module

I have pointed multiple domains to apps on the server on /var/www/ including the rails app on eurohacktrip.org

My problem is that all the other domains are also serving this same rails app.

At the bottom of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
Include sites-enabled/

LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.50/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.50
  PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/wrappers/ruby
</IfModule>
```

ON - /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/eurohacktrip.org

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName eurohacktrip.org
        ServerAlias www.eurohacktrip.org
        ServerAdmin webmaster@eurohacktrip.org

        RailsEnv production
        PassengerEnabled on
        PassengerAppRoot /var/www/eurohacktrip.org/
        PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/wrappers/ruby

        DocumentRoot /var/www/eurohacktrip.org/public

        <Directory /var/www/eurohacktrip.org/public>
                Options -MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                # Order allow,deny
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

ON - /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/tradesoko.com (laravel, php)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@tradesoko.com
        ServerName tradesoko.com
        ServerAlias www.tradesoko.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/tradesoko.com/public
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/tradesoko.com/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                # Order allow,deny
                # allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

What can I do to enable tradesoko.com?

Comment: Try moving passenger's apache module config to `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` config file and then check?

Comment: moved to /etc/apache2/httpd.conf. Still facing the same issue :(

Comment: try to change AllowOverride: `AllowOverride None` in  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/eurohacktrip.org: `<Directory /var/www/eurohacktrip.org/public>
                Options -MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                # Order allow,deny
        </Directory>`

Comment: Still that didnt help

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I am not sure what can be done here.